# How can I implement this Git testing workflow

Tags: git

I have some features that were added to a product that reveal diagnostic information. Because this information should not be revealed in production the branch is a few commits on top of master.

```
A-B-C-D-E (master)
         \
          F-G (local_testing)
```

Commits `F` and `G` make testing locally a lot easier. Now to add a feature and ensure it's working I check out a new branch `new_feature` based on `local_testing`.

```
git checkout -b new_feature local_testing
# Do work
git commit -a -m "H"
```

Commit `H` adds the needed functionality.

```
A-B-C-D-E (master)
         \
          F-G (local_testing)
             \
              H (new_feature)
```

I have been interactively rebasing to move commit `H` before commit `F`. Then I do a hard reset to move the commit object to which `new_feature` points to the new `H'`.

```
git rebase -i master
git reset --hard H
```

So the commit history looks like:

```
A-B-C-D-E (master)
         \
          H' (new_feature)
           \
            F'-G' (local_testing)
```

Then I fast-forward `master` to `new_feature` and delete `new_feature`.

```
git checkout master
git merge new_feature
git branch -d new_feature
```

This feels a bit clunky (particularly the hard reset). Is there a better way to implement this flow?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use git [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). You can from the branch master directly apply the commit H.

```
git cherry-pick <H>
```

If you have multiple new commits, you can squash them with [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).  You can also use multiple time the `git cherry-pick`command.

Comment: I would use `git cherry-pick` as well. Note that if you have multiple commits on `new_feature` you can also squash them with `git reset --soft HEAD~X`, where `X` is the number of commits to squash together.

Comment: This does not emulate the process described in the question. Importantly you still need to delete the new commits on `local_testing` and then rebase the `local_testing` branch onto the new master branch.